# Confused about integration of Java file, JSPs, servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications, servlets

This is my first time working with Java and tomcat and I'm a little confused about how everything fits together - I've googled endlessly but can't seem to wrap my head around a few concepts.

I have completed a Java program that outputs bufferedImages. My goal is to eventually get these images to display on a webpage.

I'm having trouble understanding how my java file (.java) which is currently running in NetBeans interacts with a servlet and/or JSP.

Ideally, a servlet or JSP (not 100% clear on how either of those works. I mostly understand the syntax by looking at various examples, however) could get my output (the bufferedImages) when the program runs and the HTML file could somehow interact with whatever they are doing so that the images could be displayed on the webage. I'm not sure if this is possible. If anyone could suggest a general order of going about things, that would be awesome.

In every example/tutorial i find, no one uses .java files - there are .classes in the WEB-INF folder -- it doesn't seem like people are using full on java programs. However, I need my .java program to run so that I can retrieve the output and use it on the webapp.

Any general guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to get your concepts clear man. Source code (.java) is compiled into byte code (.class) which is executed by the interpreter (JVM). Please check some tutorial on use of servlets and JSP, its pretty simple.

Comment: I agree he needs to get the concepts clear (though I have worked with web application programmers who don't seem to have bothered), but don't agree he needs a downvote for asking.  It is not a typical sort of question on SO, but I think what he's asking is on-topic, reasonable, and not readily available elsewhere.  I've attempted an answer, see what you think.  It is difficult to know where to start when you can only choose from detailed explanations (or examples) of separate technology pieces, practically all of which assume you know (at least) the basics of the other parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this kind of documentation is sadly lacking; too many think that an example is an explanation, and for all the wonderful things you can get out of an example, sometimes an explanation is not one of them.  I'm going to attempt to explain some of the overall concepts you mentioned; they aren't going to help you solve your buffered image display problem directly, unfortunately.

Tomcat and other programs like it are "web servers"; these are programs that accept internet connections from other computers and return information in a particular format.  When you enter a "www" address in a browser, the string in that address eventually ends up (as a "request") at a web server, which then returns you a web page (also called a "response").  Tomcat, Apache, Jetty, JBoss, and WebSphere are all similar programs that do this sort of thing.  In the original form of the world-wide-web, the request string represented a file on the server machine, and the web server's job was to return that (html) file for display in the browser.

A Servlet is a kind of java program that runs on some web servers.  The servlet itself is a java class with methods defined by the javax.servlet.Servlet interface.  In webservers that handle servlets, someone familiar with the configuration files can instruct the web server program to accept certain requests and, instead of returning an HTML file (or whatever) from the server, to instead execute the servlet code.  A servlet, by its nature, returns content itself - think of a program that outputs HTML and you're on the right track.

But it turns out to be a pain to output complete HTML from a program -- there's a tedious amount of HTML that doesn't have much to do with the "heavy lifting" for which you need a programming language of some sort.  You have to have Java (or some language) to make database inquiries, filter results, etc., but you don't really need Java to put in the   and the hundreds of other tags that a modern web page needs.

So a JavaServerPage (JSP) is a special kind of hybrid, a combination of HTML and things related to servlets.  You CAN put java code directly in a JSP file, but it is usually considered better to use html-like 'tags' which are then interpreted by a "JSP compiler" and turned into a servlet.  So the creator of the JSP page learns how to use these tags, which are (if correctly constructed) more logical for web page creators than the java programming language is, and in fact doesn't have to be a programmer at all.  So a programmer, working with this content-oriented person, creates tags for the page to use to describe how it wants its page to look, then the programmer does the programming and the content-person creates the web pages with it.

For your specific problem, we'll need more detail to help you.  Do you envision this program running and using some information provided by the user as part of his request to generate the images?  Or are the images generated once and now you just need to display them?  I think that's a topic for another question, actually.

This ought to be enough to get you started.  I would now suggest the wikipedia articles on these things to get more details, and good luck getting your head around the concepts.  I hope this has helped.

---

This addendum provided after a comment you made about wanting to do a slideshow.

An important web programming concept is the client-server and request-response nature of it.  In the traditional, non-Javascript web environment, the client (read browser) sends a request to the server, and the server sends back bytes.  There is no ongoing connection between the two computers after the stream of bytes finishes, and there are restrictions on how long that stream of bytes can continue.  Additionally, outside of this request and response, the server usually has no capability to send anything to the client unless the client requests it; the client 'drives' the exchange of data.

So a 'slideshow', for instance, where the server periodically sends bytes representing an additional image, is not the way HTML works (or was meant to work).  You could do one under the user's control: the user presses a button for each next picture, the browser sends a request for the next picture and it appears in the place where the previous one was.  That fits the request-response paradigm.

Now, the **effect** of an automatic slideshow is possible using Javascript.  Javascript, based on Java but otherwise unrelated, is a scripting language; it is part of an HTML page, is downloaded with the page to the browser, and it runs in the browser's environment (as opposed to a JSP/servlet, which executes on the server).  You can write a timer in Javascript, and it can wait N seconds and send another request to the server (for another picture or whatever).  Javascript has its own rules, etc., but even so I think it a good idea to keep in mind that you aren't just doing HTML any more.

If a slideshow is what you are after, then you don't need JSP at all.  You can create an HTML page with places for the picture being displayed, labels and text and etc., buttons for stopping the slideshow and so forth, in HTML, and Javascript for requesting additional pictures.

You COULD use JSP to create the page, and it might help you depending on how complex the page is, but it isn't going to help you with an essential function: getting the next picture for the slideshow.  When the browser requests a JSP page:

1. the request goes to the server,

   the server determines the page you want and that it is a JSP page,

   the server compiles that page to a servlet if it hasn't already,

   the servlet runs, producing HTML output according to the tags now compiled into Java,

   the server returns HTML to the browser.

Then the server is done, and more bytes won't go to the browser until another request is made.

Again, I hope this has helped.  Your example of a slideshow has revealed some basic concepts that need to be understood about web programming, servers, HTML, JSPs, and Javascript, and I wish you luck on your journey through them all.  And if you come to think of it all as a bit more convoluted than it seems it needed to be, well, you won't be the first.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for -- there seems to be very few tutorials that generalize the process, everything delves right into the technology. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSP that invokes a method in your Java class to retrieve the BufferedImage. Then you must set the content type to the adequate image type:

```
response.setContentType()
```

The tricky part is that you must print the image from the JSP, so you have to call:

```
response.getOutputStream()
```

from your JSP, and with that `OutputStream` you must pass the bytes of your BufferedImage.

Note that in that JSP you'll not be able to print out HTML, only the image.

I'm not sure where you need more clarification, as it seems you're a bit confused about the concepts.

BTW.: A JSP is just a servlet that has an easier syntax to write HTML and Java code together.

Comment: rcook's post clarified a lot of what I was confused about. Basically in my code, I'm using a thread to download images and a thread to read the images. My final webapp will just be a very simple site that has an image slide show (automatic). It takes no user input, the slideshow starts working on load. So, I'll just need to write scriplets in the jsp to get images from my classes if I understand correctly. I'm assuming I will have to make instances of the class in the jsp and have the class method return the pictures and then assign them to variables in the jsp document.

Comment: Well, one of the concepts I didn't have space to go into in my answer is the sometimes-confusing relationship between the client and server in the JSP world.  I'm going to edit my original answer; perhaps you'll upvote it!.